# Data from Service cannot be accessed OnInit in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, lifecycle

I created a `WorkingData` object that I use to pass certain data between components. One member of the object is `today` which is a `Date` object containing the current date. I want to update this every second in a `setInterval` function, but the `workingData` object is undefined at this point giving me the console error:

```
Cannot set property 'today' of undefined
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { WorkingData } from './services/working-data/working-data';
import { WorkingDataService } from './services/working-data/working-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ WorkingDataService ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked {

  workingData: WorkingData;

  constructor(public _workingDataService: WorkingDataService) { }

  getWorkingData() {
    this._workingDataService.getWorkingData().then(workingData => this.workingData = workingData);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getWorkingData();
    console.log('OnInit()');
    console.log(this.workingData);           // doesn't work
    // setInterval(this.updateTime(), 1000); // doesn't work
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    console.log('AfterContentChecked()');
    console.log(this.workingData);           // doesn't work the first call but does after it is called again at some later point
    // setInterval(this.updateTime(), 1000); // doesn't work
  }
  updateTime() {
      this.workingData.today = new Date();
  }
}
```

working-data.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {WorkingData} from './working-data';
import {WORKINGDATA} from './mock-working-data';

@Injectable()
export class WorkingDataService {
  getWorkingData(): Promise<WorkingData> {
    return Promise.resolve(WORKINGDATA);
  }
}
```

I'm confident the the service is valid because it generates the view using the `workingData` object and `console.log`s on a subsequent `AfterContentChecked` LifeCycle, but I cannot seem to use the object `OnInit`. I suspect I'm not using a LifeCycle hook properly, but I don't understand how to implement it correctly. **How can I immediately begin the `setInterval`?**

Comment: Why don'y you set `today` (and kick off the update interval) in the callback, when you definitely have access to `this.workingData`?

Comment: `this._workingDataService.getWorkingData()` is asynchronous. You can't get its result in `ngOnInit` synchronously. and you shouldn't. *to update this every second in a setInterval function*, an observable is better choice than a promise.

Comment: Remember you can create an Observable from a interval and subscribe to it. `Observable.interval(1000)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've added my service. Would you mind showing me show to set it up in the callback? I'm not really sure how to do callbacks with services yet.

Comment: @estus I've not yet learned observables. If it's not too much time, would you be willing to show me in this simple example?

Comment: @estus "to update this every second in a setInterval function, an observable is better choice than a promise" - it might help the op to explain why it's generally better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a use case for observables. Both promises and observables serve the same purpose when an asynchronous operation should result in a single value.

For multiple values observables is better choice because it is their primary purpose.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
...
export class AppComponent {
  workingData$: Observable<WorkingData>;

  constructor(public _workingDataService: WorkingDataService) {
    this.workingData$ = Observable.interval(1000).startWith('initial value')
    .concatMapTo(Observable.fromPromise(_workingDataService.getWorkingData()))
    .do(data => data.today = new Date)

}
```

`workingData` result can be obtained with

```
    this.workingData$.subscribe(data => this.workingData = data);
```

But in most scenarios it will be redundant, because `workingData$` can be subscribed wherever needed, and observables can be bound in view with `async` pipe:

```
{{ workingData$ | async }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to alter the data before it's resolved. `getWorkingData()` is asynchronous function that's returning a promise, not the actual data. Try doing your updates when the data is actually available (in the callback).

```
getWorkingData() {
  return this._workingDataService.getWorkingData();
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getWorkingData().then(workingData => {
    this.workingData = workingData;
    // do your magic here
    });
...
}
```

Comment: Starting the interval after the observable resolves in ngOnInit seems logical

Comment: I agree this seems logical too, but I'm getting the same error. I know the service is working though, because other components render its data in the view using the same service.

Comment: Can you update the code in the original post now, so we can see how it looks at the moment?